# Jenkins pipeline how to use string interpolation correctly

Tags: docker, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

In my docker run, I would like to pass a secret as an env variable. And that works just fine. However, I also have a second variable "foo" that I would like to echo inside my container. This does not work. How can I get the variable "foo" to expand inside the triple single quotes?

```
 stages {
        stage('test') {
            steps {
                    script {
                        def foo = "bar"
                        sh '''
                        docker run \
                                --rm \
                                --env secret=$ENV_SECRET \
                                python:3.8.12 /bin/bash -c \
                                "echo $foo"
                        '''
                    
                }
                
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Secrets should be handled specially in Jenkins pipelines! See [`environment { ... credentials('...') } }`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#environment).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for interpolating strings with Groovy variables in Groovy involves `"`. If your `ENV_SECRET` is an environment variable bound from a `withCredentials` block, then you want to interpolate it within the shell interpreter. Therefore, we can update your shell step method with:

```
sh """
  docker run \
  --rm \
  --env secret=\$ENV_SECRET \
  python:3.8.12 /bin/bash -c \
  'echo $foo'
"""
```

Your syntax would have interpolated shell variables instead. Note that both will interpolate environment variables, but with different interpreters.

Comment: Reference: [Groovy, Syntax, Triple-double-quoted string](http://www.groovy-lang.org/syntax.html#_triple_double_quoted_string)

Comment: Doing it this way generates a warning in Jenkins

The following steps that have been detected may have insecure interpolation of sensitive variables (click here for an explanation):

Comment: Just escape `$` for each secret. `""" ... secret=\$ENV_SECRET ..."""`

Comment: @Kinder9211 If your `ENV_SECRET` is an environment variable bound from a `withCredentials` block, then you want to interpolate it within the shell interpreter. In that situation, daggett is completely correct and I will update the answer.

Comment: Yes that was what i was looking for, because the explanation given by jenkins was to enclose it in single quotes :)